# Can not install annotations

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I tried installing annotations for symfony. But I can not install it.

composer require annotations

I tried writing "composer require annotations"
-> https://save.jb-dev.eu/img/NWgZ7LPOv0.png

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: please read this carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and insert image properly not the only link.

Comment: Could you post your composer.json ?

Comment: The solution is there in your screen snippet, isn't it? `composer require doctrine/annotations`. Else you'll have to follow [habibhun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56210103/1155833) to start using [Symfony Flex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use Symfony flex

```
composer require annotations
```

if you don't use Symfony Flex, add it to your composer.json file

or you can use this command

```
composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

Answer (score 3):

First, try the following command,

`composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle`

Then run this command,

`composer require annotation`

Then it will work perfect.